# PHP + CURL example to post form data and receive response

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to post form data to a remote server, using PHP and Curl, I also want to get the server response to the posted data.

I have written a function to post the data to the server using Curl. However I want to get the sever response to the POSTed data. The server response will be in JSON

So I am looking to write a function like this:

```
public function postFormDataAndGetResponse()
{
   // use curl to post form data (this I have already done)

   // now what Curl options to use to wait (up to a TIMEOUT interval) to receive json data from server?
}
```

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Rolled back, as it may be useful for others. (btw, IIRC you can accept after 15 minutes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, simple example:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$recived_content = curl_exec($ch); 
$data = json_decode($recived_content);
```

Comment: Use curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) to get http response code if you need it.

Comment: Ah yes, I found it. I tried to delete question. I will accept your answer when I am allowed.